How to automatically flush permalinks?
Is it possible to write function that will trigger flush_rewrite_rules() on a timer? I would like for it to run every hour

it's possible but why would you want to?

This sounds like an XY problem: https://xyproblem.info/

To automatically flush permalinks every hour, use the following code:

Hook the scheduling function to init.
Schedule an hourly event if not already scheduled.
Hook the scheduled event to a function.
Define the function to flush rewrite rules.

// Hook the scheduling function
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_my_hourly_event' );

// Schedule the event
function schedule_my_hourly_event() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
    }
}

// Hook the event to a function
add_action( 'my_hourly_event', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules' );

// Function to flush rewrite rules
function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}


I downvoted because lots of time, it's not a good idea to do that and it's better to think deeper on the goal to find another way of working.
